# Cant start jetty from terminal - get error on start up

Tags: solr, jetty, osx-elcapitan

directory where the jetty is installed, i used brew install jetty

```
Vallis-MacBook-Pro:9.3.7.v20160115 ValliSA$ cd libexec/
Vallis-MacBook-Pro:libexec ValliSA$ ls -ltr
total 1208
drwxr-xr-x  60 ValliSA  admin    2040 Jan 15 16:37 modules
drwxr-xr-x   8 ValliSA  admin     272 Jan 15 17:04 demo-base
drwxr-xr-x   3 ValliSA  admin     102 Jan 15 17:05 webapps
drwxr-xr-x   3 ValliSA  admin     102 Jan 15 17:05 resources
drwxr-xr-x   3 ValliSA  admin     102 Jan 15 17:05 bin
drwxr-xr-x  44 ValliSA  admin    1496 Jan 15 17:05 lib
-rw-r--r--   1 ValliSA  admin    3978 Jan 15 17:05 start.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 ValliSA  admin  142605 Jan 15 17:06 start.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 ValliSA  admin   30012 Jan 15 17:06 license-eplv10-aslv20.html
drwxr-xr-x  50 ValliSA  admin    1700 Jan 15 17:06 etc
-rw-r--r--   1 ValliSA  admin  428261 Jan 15 17:06 VERSION.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 ValliSA  admin       5 Feb  7 19:05 jetty.pid
drwxr-xr-x   4 ValliSA  admin     136 Feb  7 19:05 logs
-rw-r--r--   1 ValliSA  admin      98 Feb  7 19:05 jetty.state
```

here is where i start jetty

```
 Vallis-MacBook-Pro:libexec ValliSA$ java -jar start.jar
```

after executing start i get below exception and am not sure how to resolve the issue.

```
 2016-02-07 19:06:08.794:INFO::main: Logging initialized @591ms
    2016-02-07 19:06:08.892:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance            of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not     recommended.  See documentation at      http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
    2016-02-07 19:06:09.134:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.7.v20160115
    2016-02-07 19:06:09.160:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment     monitor [file:///usr/local/Cellar/jetty/9.3.7.v20160115/libexec/webapps/]    at interval 1
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:6   2)
```

Comment: This error seems pretty clear: `This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended.`  Did you `See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html`?

Comment: Hi Ian, i did see the documentation but am not clear on how to resolve this issue.although the  instance of hetty not running from a separate directory is just a warning, not sure if that is really causing the start up to fail with error message.

Comment: so do you suggest me to move the jetty installable contents to a different directory and run from there? right now it is installed under /usr/local/Cellar/jetty

Comment: Honestly I know nothing about Jetty or what you are doing, but the error message sounded pretty clear.  I just wanted to clarify you'd seen that message and followed the link (many many users asking questions don't get that far).

Comment: Actually am trying to do a data migration from a MySql database to Solr, basically using Solr as a search engine for my facebook app. As part of the same, i installed Solr, and while trying to integrate MySql, i found that i needed to start the jetty server, and hence installed jetty

Comment: Solr is typically bundled with its own Jetty, and is generally speaking (there are exceptions) [not meant to be deployed / installed as a normal webapp](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar).

Comment: Hi Joakim, I totally get your point, however when i execute java -jar start.jar from solr directory itself it says nothing to start.. please see below, also as mentioned in various articles in my installation start.jar is not in example directory rather it is in server directory.


Vallis-MacBook-Pro:server ValliSA$ java -jar start.jar 
WARNING: Nothing to start, exiting ...

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information
Vallis-MacBook-Pro:server ValliSA$

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend installing Jetty and then trying to configure Solr into it (if that's indeed what you're trying to do), *especially* if you're using the latest version of Solr (5.4.1). As of 5.3, Solr is designed to be a standalone server. If, for some bizarre reason, you want to make things hard on yourself and put bits and pieces of Solr into Jetty when an official Solr download *would already have this done for you*, you need to go to, at the latest, 5.2.1. The only time I've seen people pick apart a Solr download is when using a different container, like Tomcat.

Not only that, but you shouldn't be using `start.jar` to start Solr. You should be using the scripts in `bin/solr`. I want to stress here that you're not starting *Jetty* in this situation, you're starting *Solr*.

[Start here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/mirrors-solr-latest-redir.html) to be directed to the closest mirror for a Solr 5.4.1 download. Read the documentation or find a good tutorial and you'll have Solr doing what you want soon enough.

You shouldn't need to `brew install jetty` in this case.